# WPF basic Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf

Im new to WPF and Iv been breaking my head over this for past couple of days. I am trying to set a basic binding of textbox to a string property. I followed the MS tutorial but nothing seems to be working.

Here's email class, I am trying to bind its subject property to display in a textbox

```
public class Email : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _subject;

    public string Subject
    {
        get { return _subject; }
        set
        {
            _subject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Subject");
        }
    }

    private string _contents;

    public string Contents
    {
        get { return _contents; }
        set
        {
            _contents = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Contents");
        }
    }

    private Category _category;

    public Category Category
    {
        get { return _category; }
        set
        {
            _category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Category");
        }
    }

    public Email()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the email setter inside UserControl that parents the textbox:

```
private Email _email;

public Email Email
{
    get { return _email; }
    set
    {
        _email = value;
        if (_email != null)
        {
            Binding myBinding = new Binding("Subject");
            myBinding.Source = _email;
            tbSubject.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
        }
    }
}
```

tbSubject is never getting set to anything, its always empty even if email passed is not null and has a subject! If I do just this:

```
public Email Email
{
    get { return _email; }
    set
    {
        _email = value;
        if (_email != null)
        {
            tbSubject.Text = _email.Subject;
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine. I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try placing `_email.OnPropertyChanged("Subject")` after setting the binding.

Comment: no doesn't work, Ive also tried changing subject after binding. Textbox is still empty :/

Comment: @LPL - Binding `Path` should be a property. Source need not to be a property.

Comment: I have partial success with calling DataContext = this; prior to setting binding. It works but only for the first email once. After that it stops working.

Comment: Thou have any sources on that, @RohitVats?

Comment: @Stefan Denchev - You can just try it with a field and it will work.

Comment: @RohitVats I know that :P... Thanks anyway...

Comment: Asking for a source for a known fact. Strange..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. Here's the change I had to make:

```
    public partial class EmailContentsTemplate : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Email _email;

    public Email Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }


    public EmailContentsTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        Binding myBinding = new Binding("Email.Subject");
        myBinding.Source = this;
        tbSubject.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

So I changed source to "this" and made the user control implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Now it works.

Alternatively I got it working through XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbSubject" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Email.Subject}"/>
```

Comment: I think you've stumbled on the reason why OP was not working which was partially related the fact that property changed notification was not raised when the Email codebehind member changed. So this solution will work but you can still do better in that your `UserControl` should not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but rather only the view model/binding source should. IMO, you need something like an EmailContentsViewModel that "has a" EmailViewModel member (both types implementing INotifyPropertyChanged or better yet, inheriting from a common view model base class that does).